# Prevent the android app from running if packet capture or any sniffer is installed on the phone

Tags: android, java

I want to make my Android app secure. In some applications, if the phone has a network sniffer program installed(packet capture,ssl capture etc), the application gives an alert(Remove packet capture) and turns off. How do I add a similar security measure? What technologies should I look for ?

[image: The app first wants me to uninstall packet sniffer program]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ConnectivityManager to detect VPN Service enabled or not. Using that I stop calling api calls.

To detect VPN enabled or not :

```
fun isVPNEnabled(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    return if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val network = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
        val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(network)
        capabilities!= null && capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN)
    } else {
        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_VPN)!!.isConnectedOrConnecting
    }
}
```

If VPN enabled stop the api call using interceptor:

```
class VPNInterceptor(val context: Context) : Interceptor {
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val codeSnippet = CodeSnippet(context)
    return if (codeSnippet.isVPNEnabled()) {
        Timber.d("====>VPN Status : true")
        val errorResponse = ErrorResponse("Please turn-off VPN service for security reason.", true)
        Response.Builder()
            .code(Constants.InternalHttpCode.VPN_CODE) // Whatever code
            .body(ResponseBody.create(null, "")) // Whatever body
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
            .message(errorResponse.moshiObjToString(ErrorResponse::class.java))
            .request(chain.request())
            .build()
    } else {
        Timber.d("====>VPN Status : false")
        chain.proceed(chain.request())
    }
}
```

}

```
val httpClient: OkHttpClient.Builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    httpClient.connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES) //Connection time out set limit
    httpClient.readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)  //Connection read time out set limit
    httpClient.addInterceptor(VPNInterceptor(context))
```

Comment: can you add Java code?

Answer (score 2):

You won't make your application more secure by disabling it when a network sniffer is installed. As a user, I would be very annoyed by such so-called security measures which are ineffective.

To secure your application, you should consider what an attacker would do. Assuming that you are worried about network traffic analysis, note that there are active and passive attacks.

### Passive attack

Includes network sniffing, network monitoring, etc. The attacker can use [VPNService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService) on the Android phone itself to monitor all traffic without root. Sure, you can try to detect that based on installed apps and block that, but then the attacker will move on and setup an external capture. They could setup an access point on their laptop and connect the phone to it and run a network capture from the laptop.

To properly protect you against this class of attackers, ensure that your communications are encrypted (using HTTPS/TLS). Then it doesn't matter whether someone is able to record network traffic on the phone or local network, they will only be able to see the destination IP address and hostname, but not actual request details (URLs, cookies, etc.)

### Active attacks

Includes man-in-the-middle (MitM), SSL/TLS proxying, etc. An attacker who controls the network can intercept connections and try to pretend to be the server. This is trivial if the traffic is not secured with TLS. Though even if you do implement TLS, you must still validate the certificate presented by the server. A TLS proxy won't be able to show a valid certificate that is signed by a trusted CA, so normally this is fine.

A user can however add their own CA to the device which would allow them to read the unencrypted application traffic again. To protect against this, you could consider certificate pinning. That way, you hardcode the trusted certificates in your application without the user being able to override it in the usual way.

Finally note that a determined attacker can also patch (modify) your apk, install it in an emulator, or try to decompile it. From that they could also learn how to communicate with the server. Keep this scenario in mind while developing the server.

### Further reading

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl